# What does local do on the standard streams / bareword word filehandles: STDIN?

Tags: perl, scope, stdin, filehandle

I was thinking about doing

```
open(*STDIN, "<", "/dev/null" );
open(my $fh, "-|", "/bin/bash", "/tmp/foo");
print for <$fh>;'
```

However, I would like `*STDIN` restored, afterward, so I tried.

```
{
  open(local *STDIN, "<", "/dev/null" );
  open(my $fh, "-|", "/bin/bash", "/tmp/foo");
  print for <$fh>;
}
```

You can try this with `cat` with and without the `local` keyword like this,

```
{
  # remove local and it works,
  open(local *STDIN, "<", "/dev/null" );
  open(my $fh, "-|", "/bin/cat");
  print for <$fh>;
}
```

**Only without** `local` will `cat` read from `/dev/null`. So what does `local` actually do on a bareword filehandle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are system files handles (called file descriptors, or "fd"), and there are Perl file handles. Perl file handles usually wrap a system file handles, but this isn't always the case. For example, `open(my $fh, '<', \$buf)` creates a Perl handle that isn't associated with any system file handle.

Other processes don't know anything about your process's variables, so they don't know anything about Perl file handles. Whatever handle is opened as fd 0 will be used as STDIN, fd 1 as STDOUT, and fd 2 as STDERR.<sup>[1]</sup>

When `open` is passed an existing Perl handle, this handle will be closed. If creating a new system file handle, it will be either be given the same number as the original fd (if the original handle had one) or the lowest available number (if it didn't).<sup>[2]</sup>

So, when you use `open(*STDIN, ...)`, the new handle associated with `*STDIN{IO}` will also be fd 0.

```
$ perl -e'
   CORE::say fileno(*STDIN);
   open(*STDIN, "<", "/dev/null") or die $!;
   CORE::say fileno(*STDIN);
'
0
0
```

`cat`, reading from fd 0, will therefore notice the change.

`local *STDIN` creates a backup of the glob and associated `*STDIN` with a fresh glob. The original `*STDIN` is still in memory, so no resources associated with `*STDIN` are freed. This means that any file handle associated with `*STDIN` is still open.

When you use `open(local *STDIN, ...)`, the new fd will have the lowest number available. fd 0 is still being used by the original `*STDIN` somewhere in memory, so fd 0 is not available. Maybe fd 3 will be the first available fd this time (1 and 2 being used by STDOUT and STDERR).

```
$ perl -e'
   CORE::say fileno(*STDIN);
   {  
      open(local *STDIN, "<", "/dev/null") or die $!;
      CORE::say fileno(*STDIN);
   }
   CORE::say fileno(*STDIN);
'
0
3
0
```

`cat`, reading from fd 0, will read from the original handle.

Perl could make it so whatever handles are associated with STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR become fd 0, 1 and 2 before executing `cat`, but it doesn't. This is left to you.

---

1. While I'm describing how things work in unixy systems, things work similarly in Windows.
2. In the situation where `open` is passed a handle that wraps a system file handle and a new system file handle is also being created, the internal mechanism used on unixy system is the following:

   1. A new fd is created using `open`. It will have the lowest available number.
   2. `dup2` is used to create a duplicate of the new fd with the same number as the original fd.
   3. The fd created by `open` is closed.

   This means the original fd isn't closed if an error occurs.

Comment: *"Perl could make it so whatever handles are associated with STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR become fd 0, 1 and 2 before executing cat, but it doesn't. This is left to you."* That beautifully and succinctly shows the misunderstanding. That certainly would make for a better user interface, imho.

Comment: What you're describing in the 3rd paragraph is complete fantasy. When you use `open(*STDIN, "file")`, perl will first open(2) "file", then dup2(2) the returned file descriptor into fd 0. It makes no sense to first close the file descriptor associated with stdin, since opening the new file may fail. And in fact, perl is not doing that, which a simple strace or source code perusal would show you.

Answer (score 4):

`open ...,'-|'` and `system` calls that read from standard input will try to read from file descriptor 0. If you don't mess that up, the external programs will read from the same input stream as perl's standard input.

```
# reads from standard input
open my $fh, '-|', "/bin/cat";
while (<fh>) { print }

# reads from /tmp/foo
open STDIN, "<", "/tmp/foo";       # replaces fd0 with handle to /tmp/foo
open my $fh, '-|', "/bin/cat";
while (<$fh>) { print }

# reads from standard input
open local *STDIN, "<", "/tmp/foo";  # doesn't close fd0, creates new fd
open my $fh, '-|',  "/bin/cat";
while (<$fh>) { print }

# reads from /tmp/foo
close STDIN;
open FOO, "<", "/tmp/foo";       # fileno(FOO) should be 0 now
open my $fh, '-|', "/bin/cat";
while (<$fh>) { print }
```

Comment: That's just a really weird unintuitive undocumented behavior of `local *STDIN`. I would expect it to stash the old value, and return it after scope (like it does with everything else). Though at least you've told me what it's doing.

Comment: `*STDIN` is a typeglob (holding package data in the `STDIN` namespace), not just a fileglob. `local *STDIN` creates a new typeglob but doesn't affect anything in the original `*STDIN` namespace, so it doesn't affect what I/O stream file descriptor 0 is attached to.